# VBA- Code executes and produces desired effect but then errors on Exportasfixedformat line

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a macro for exporting all worksheets to seperate pdfs in a specified sub-folder. When I execute it produces the pdfs in the correct location and titled apporproately but then errors- Error 5 Invalid procedure call or argument- Any ideas?

```
    Sub SaveWorkshetAsPDF()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim path As String
Dim fol As String
Dim name As String
Dim concat As String
Dim fdObj As Object


path = ActiveWorkbook.path
fol = "\PDFs\"
Set fdObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If fdObj.FolderExists(path & fol) Then
MsgBox "Found it", vbInformation
Else
fdObj.createfolder (path & fol)
MsgBox "folder created", vbInformation
End If

For Each ws In Worksheets


    name = ws.name
    concat = path & fol & name

    With ws.PageSetup
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = False
        .PaperSize = xlPaperA3
    End With
    ws.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, fileName:=concat
Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

add the file extension and also the ActiveWorkBook

```
For Each ws In Worksheets


name = ws.name
concat = path & fol & name & ".pdf"

With ws.PageSetup
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = False
    .PaperSize = xlPaperA3
End With
ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, Filename:=concat
Next ws
```